# Build Successful, Archive Not visible in Xcode 9.2

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have upgraded to `Xcode 9.2`, my project got successfully build and is getting installed on simulator and device.
But when I tried to generate build for release through Archive, even though it says archive is successful, no archive is getting generated in the window.

[image]

I have tried all options mentioned in below link but no solution for me :(
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2215/_index.html

[image]

[image: greyed out validate button]

Comment: Unclear what you expect. That is not the archives window so naturally you don't see any archives in it!

Comment: Also you've got 211 warnings. I wouldn't release like that if I were you.

Comment: What you built, according to your first screen shot, was the Jama2 target, so click Jama2 under Other Items.

Comment: i have done that... i am getting as generice xcode archive..with validate button greyed out..

Comment: Please search for "generic xcode archive" on Stack Overflow.

Comment: `Validate` Option disabled because release build archived by using `iOS Developer` certificate. Please use distribution certificate for creating IPA.

Comment: Problem got solved. I removed all node_module folder in react-native, done a fresh install, removed npm cached, revoked & created new developer certificate and then finally it worked.

Thanks for the help